# How to persist redux state with gatsby?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm using redux with gatsby by installing these packages :

```
react react-redux gatsby-plugin-react-redux
```

This is store.js file :

```
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import { reducer } from './reducer';
export default (preloadedState) => {
    return createStore(reducer, preloadedState);
};
```

gatsby-config.js

```
module.exports = {
    plugins: [
        {
            resolve: `gatsby-plugin-react-redux`,
            options: {
                pathToCreateStoreModule: './src/redux/store',
                cleanupOnClient: false
            }
        }
    ]
};
```

I've set cleanupOnClient to false but still when I refresh the page , the state is still the old version and it has not been persisted.

How can I persist redux state changes with gatsby ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added redux-persist to gatsby-plugin-react-redux, you can find it here:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/gatsby-plugin-react-redux-persist

it's the first release but seems to work :)

edit:

I see that redux-persist goes to timeout during rehydratation when using preloadedState, I don't know if it happens to you too, btw you can skip it:

```
export default () => {
  const store = createStore(
    persistedReducer,
    {}, // initial state
  );
  const persistor = persistStore(store);
  return { store, persistor };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I like the idea behind the persist plugin, but I found that with the createStore composition, it was easy to cause issues for other libraries wanting access to the store.

Instead I added redux-persist to my existing gatsby-plugin-react-redux setup:

**createStore.js**

```
import { compose, createStore } from 'redux'
import { persistReducer } from 'redux-persist'
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage'

import initialState from './initialState'
import rootReducer from './rootReducer'

const persistedReducer = persistReducer({
  key: 'root',
  storage
}, rootReducer);

const composeEnhancers = (typeof window === 'object') ? window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ : undefined

const store = () => {
  return createStore(
    persistedReducer,
    initialState,
    composeEnhancers ? composeEnhancers() : compose
  );
}
```

**gatsby-browser.js wrapper**

```
import React from 'react'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { PersistGate } from 'redux-persist/integration/react'
import { persistStore } from 'redux-persist'
import createStore from './src/state/createStore'

export const wrapRootElement = ({ element, props }) => {
  const store = createStore()

  const persistor = persistStore(store)

  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
        {element}
      </PersistGate>
    </Provider>
  )
}
```